# Clustered Redis 6.x dump restore to standalone redis in AWS Elasticache

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, amazon-elasticache

We need to migrate from clustered Redis instance to no-clustered Redis instances in AWS Elasticache due to the incompatibility of certain drivers in our application but AWS does not allow creating non-clustered instances from clustered backup.

Is there any way by which we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to save the backup in S3 and create non-clustered instance from s3 backup.